# How do I use Android's adb command while logged in as another user?

Tags: android, adb

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and a Samsung Galaxy S3 and am currently experiencing some trouble with Android's adb command in my project.  Here's the situation (it's a bit weird): I can use adb fine when I'm logged into my normal Ubuntu account; however, when I perform a `sudo su *another_user*` and then try to execute `adb kill-server; adb devices`, adb no longer sees my plugged-in device.

If I then log out of ubuntu and log back into the *another_user* account, adb works fine. I'm stumped.

Here are my udev rules. The udev service has been restarted multiple times through service restarts and reboots.

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", OWNER="my_account", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Both the *my_account* and *another_user* accounts have been added to the plugdev group and the machine was restarted.  Can anyone else verify this issue?  Can anyone possibly identify a solution?

Comment: Why do you think you need to do `adb kill-server`?

Comment: Need the other user to be able to start adb without the need for it having been run from another session.  The kill-server command was just a way of ensuring that this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to start the adb daemon as root, and leave it alone after that.

```
sudo adb start-server
```

Do this after each reboot, and then any account can use adb.